# Measurement of blocking artifacts in images

Tags: image-processing, signal-analysis, noise, image-compression, jpeg

I want to define a threshold for maximal blocking artifacts in an image.

What is a good key value to measure blocking artifacts?

- I have no reference image
- non natural image

Example:

[image: Image with artifacts]

I looked into no reference image quality analysis like BRISQUE and PIQE, but they seem to be more focused on natural images.

Other methods like peak signal to noise ratio only work with a reference image if I understood correctly.

Use case: user uploads image chart, blockiness value will be calculated, if over threshold image will not be accepted.

Comment: Welcome here. I can see some blocking artifacts, yet also some annoying mosquito effects

Comment: thanks for welcoming me here. If you have any ideas about measuring blocky artifacts (from jpeg compression), let me know. I came across this artifacts removal repository (https://github.com/jiaxi-jiang/FBCNN). It can be tested here https://huggingface.co/spaces/danielsapit/JPEG_Artifacts_Removal.
My idea is to remove the artifacts from an image and take the resulting image as a reference. This way I can calculate e.g. PSNR and try other methods which are reference based

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case somebody in the future looks for an answer. There are several metrics proposed to measure blocky artifacts.

- MUG: A Parameterless No-Reference JPEG Quality
  Evaluator Robust to Block Size and Misalignment
  https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=7565477
- BLIND MEASUREMENT OF BLOCKING ARTIFACTS IN IMAGES
  https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=899622
- Referenceless Measure of Blocking Artifacts
  by Tchebichef Kernel Analysis
  https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6679216
- Learning Structural Regularity for Evaluating
  Blocking Artifacts in JPEG Images
  https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6807665
- New No-reference Blocking Artifacts Metric
  Based on Human Visual System
  https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5371672
- No-Reference Quality Assessment for JPEG
  Compressed Images
  https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=7965629
- NO-REFERENCE PERCEPTUAL QUALITY ASSESSMENT OF JPEG COMPRESSED
  IMAGES
  https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=1038064
- No-Reference JPEG Image Quality Assessment
  Based on Blockiness and Luminance Change
  https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=7888493